# MySQL results issue when the value has number ending with string

Tags: mysql, sql, select, casting, conditional-statements

Can anyone point out this behaviour and hw to stop this ?

I know about casting or adding double quotes.

I was wondering if there is any other way

Heres table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `country_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

[image]

The record with id 1 is correct but id 2 doesn't satisfy the where condition but is returned.

Comment: Is there any TABLE Definition changes that can fix this ?

Comment: No there isn't you have to code for it.

Comment: Tell doctrine that country_name you search for is a string, and don't hand over an integer

Comment: Undeniably, it *is* a strange name for a country

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from countries where country_name='7884'
```

Comment: Correct, like I said I know this is the fix. But I'm using Laravel (Doctrine) and the driver is firing the query.. 
So I was wondering of a structure wise solution, that way I won't have to make changes in every file / conditions with such case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you write `country_name = 7884`, that `country_name` is implicitly casted as a `signed integer`. And in the casting process the `'S'` is simply ignored, as you can see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/51376). That selects the second row because `cast('1884S' AS signed)` = `1884` = `1884` (your input).

As fa06 already suggested, surround the operand by single quotes to make it a string and prevent the implicit cast -- `... where country_name = '7884'`.

Comment: Any configuration at mysql settings level to prevent from this auto casting ?